# Почему CustomTabs не закрывается после успешной авторизации?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, oauth, android-manifest

Использую библиотеку [AppAuth](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) для авторизации в ВКонтакте. После разрешения доступа открывается ссылка `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=...`. Но CustomTabs автоматически не закрывается, чтобы вернуться в приложение. Если закрыть руками, приложение ловит событие отмены, то есть слушатель на стороне активности работает.

Ниже фрагмент манифеста с фильтром на отлов этой ссылки. Почему он может не работать?
Пробовал делать отдельный тег с `intent-filter`, добавлять `autoVerify="true"`. Во всех случаях вкладка не закрывается сама.

```
<activity
    android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    tools:node="replace">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="${applicationId}" />

        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:host="oauth.vk.com" />
        <data android:path="/blank.html" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Возможно у вас подтверждение о успешной авторизации не ловится. Сверьте манифест с примером отсюда https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android, я давно уже AppAuth не занимался, но мне кажется ваш `data` тег неверно задан.